# doc file not displayed in jsp

Tags: java, html, hibernate, jsp

I am doing a JSP site,using hibernate 
 where I need to display PDF files,doc files  etc . I have byte array of PDF/doc file by webservice and I need to display that byte array as PDF file/doc  in HTML.i convet this into pdf by using the following code and its correctly shows in html page

```
   byte[] pdf = new byte[] {}; // Load PDF byte[] into here
                if (pdf != null) {

                    // set pdf content
                    response.setContentType("application/pdf");

                    // write the content to the output stream
                    BufferedOutputStream fos1 = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        response.getOutputStream());
                    fos1.write(ba1);
                    fos1.flush();
                    fos1.close();
       }
```

for  doc file i change the  response.ContentType  from

```
   response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    to 
    response.setContentType( "application/msword" );
```

but  instead of displaying its is showing a down load window.how can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
01 response.setContentLength(pdf.length);
```

Any proxy or antivirus or firewall may guess the download is completed. So inform the browser how many bytes you wish to transfer.

Comment: @Peter Rader  its is not working ,for pdf its is working .i have prolem for doc files its shows a download window instead of display the doc file

Comment: What if you install the doc-viewer from microsoft.com?